# Is there any way to set length of integer array with variable in hlsl?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, cg

firstly, I wish you guys can understand awkward grammar skills of next writing. English is not my first language.

Im currently using UnityEngine Now. what i wanna do is sending a number of rows to a shader, so that i can set a count of rows of stripes in Gameobject mesh using the shader which got the number of stripes.

And I made to send a number variable to a shader, but when i try to create int array in CG program part(which is HLSL) with size of the rows that i want using the number, unity Engine gives me this error message - "array dimensions must be literal scalar expressions".

This is the integer variable that i set in my unity shader script. This gets integer value from c# script function(this part doenst have any issue)

```
_LowCount ("LowCount", int) = 0
```

And this is CG Program part which im struggling with.
The variable below is declared in global field. It receives number value from the properties.

```
int _LowCount;
```

And this is fragment shader function part and it declares integer array in its local field setting the array size on integer variable - "_LowCount"

```
fixed4 frag(v2f i):COLOR{
                fixed4 c=0;
                int ColorsArray[_LowCount];
                for(int aa=0;aa<_LowCount;aa++){
                    ColorsArray[aa]=0;
                }
return c;
```

And below part from fragment shader function gives me the error that i mentioned in above.

```
int ColorsArray[_LowCount];
```

I searched this issue in google, then i realized i have to set array size with number value( not a variable). But I need an integer array with size of number variable that i can give any integer value anytime i want. Is there any solution?

*ps. I started to learn CG graphics from just 2 weeks ago. So I might be wrong in my understading and my knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need a variable sized array?

Comment: @Kyysel hlsl is not c sharp and does not have a `List` type

Comment: @muute use the maximum size you will support as a literal and also set an integer telling it how many values to read from the array.

Comment: @shingo i wanna use this shader to multiple different objects. Ofc, effect from the shader has to work diffrently on each object. A variable sized Array is for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to define an hlsl array with variable size. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-data-types):

> Literal scalar expressions declared containing most other types

Either preallocate with the maximum array size `int ColorsArray[maximum possible _LowCount];`

It's not super clear what your end goal is, but another solution may be to execute a different shader for each object instead. See if you can update your question a little and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hello . Thank you for your answer, but i already finished my project. and  I used the same way like you said -  preallocating with the maximum array size. I had tried to find ways for my question after i uploaded this question, but i couldnt find any but preallocation. But, anyway, thank you for your kind answer : )